# open file with Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, image, file, picturebox, guid

So, I am copied images and renamed thems by GUID and didn't meet any problems.
But when I wanted to open this image for example into picturebox, I got this:
[image]

Generated name with path in debuger looks like:`@"images\full_45e72053-440f-4f20-863c-3d80ef96876f.jpeg"`

How I can open this file?

This is my code which show me this problem:

```
private void picBoxMini2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageFolderPath"].ToString();
            string imgName = this.picBoxMini2.ImageLocation;
            string[] tmp = imgName.Split('_');
            this.picBoxMain.Image = Image.FromFile($"{dir}\full_{tmp[tmp.Length - 1]}");
        }
```

ImageLocation contains 100% info, I insured on this situation:

```
 string dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageFolderPath"].ToString();
            if (imgs.Length >= 1)
            {
                this.picBoxMain.Image = Image.FromFile($@"{dir}\full_{imgs[0]}");
                this.picBoxMain.ImageLocation = $@"{dir}\full_{imgs[0]}";
                this.picBoxMini1.Image = Image.FromFile($@"{dir}\85_{imgs[0]}");
                this.picBoxMini1.ImageLocation = $@"{dir}\85_{imgs[0]}";

                this.picBoxMini2.Image = null;
                this.picBoxMini2.ImageLocation = null;
                this.picBoxMini3.Image = null;
                this.picBoxMini3.ImageLocation = null;
            }
            if (imgs.Length >= 2)
            {
                this.picBoxMini2.Image = Image.FromFile($@"{dir}\85_{imgs[1]}");
                this.picBoxMini2.ImageLocation = $@"{dir}\85_{imgs[1]}";
            }
            if (imgs.Length == 3)
            {
                this.picBoxMini3.Image = Image.FromFile($@"{dir}\85_{imgs[2]}");
                this.picBoxMini3.ImageLocation = $@"{dir}\85_{imgs[2]}";
            }
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `@` on your `.FromFile` call  in the first code block.

Comment: @BradleyUffner YES is it! I was so exhausted and miss this symbol. Now all perfectly works! THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
this.picBoxMain.Image = Image.FromFile($"{dir}\full_{tmp[tmp.Length - 1]}");
```

You forgot the `@` that tells the compiler to treat the string as verbatim.  Without that mark it thinks your path has an embedded ctrl+f character (from the \f in `\full`), which is not a legal character for filenames in Windows.

Your options are:

- Include the `@`: `this.picBoxMain.Image = Image.FromFile($@"{dir}\full_{tmp[tmp.Length - 1]}")`
- Escape the directory separator: `this.picBoxMain.Image = Image.FromFile($"{dir}\\full_{tmp[tmp.Length - 1]}")`
- Do something else fancy with `System.IO.Path.Combine` to automatically handle the directory / filename separators. `this.picBoxMain.Image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, $"full_{tmp[tmp.Length - 1]}"))` (This probably the safest, most portable solution, but it might be overkill for your needs.)